# How do I order the gcc compiler to generate -S flag in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, gcc

How can I set the Arduido IDE to generate the `-S` flag to gcc to see the machine code in Arduino? (the sketches)

Comment: avr-gcc's switch "-S" means "Compile only; do not assemble or link". Are you thinking of avr-objdump? It's "-S" switch means "Intermix source code with disassembly".

Answer (score 2):

Compiler flags are defined in the platform.txt of the board you have selected in the **Tools > Board** menu. You can also add compiler flags via a `build.extra_flags` property in the boards.txt entry for the selected board.